# Isabelle / isar: Implementing equational reasoning

Tags: equality, isabelle, isar

I'm still trying to get my head around equality relations and how to define one in Isabelle. Luckily there is a chapter about this in the isar reference manual 2.3.1 p38f.

I tried to rebuild the given example. To avoid any overlaps with the established syntax i renamed everything. Also i added some quotationmarks, since they seem to be missing in the example.

```
theory playground
imports Main
begin

typedecl i_play
typedecl u_play
```

The next step is the judgment i don't really understand, but hey what can go wrong:

```
judgment
Trueprop :: "u_play => prop" ("_play" 5)

error: Attempt to redeclare object-logic judgment
```

even renaming Trueprop doesn't yield another result.

Can't i somehow use bool here instead of defining my own object proposition?
Or do i need to introduce u_play somewhere else?

But let's go further. The next step is the equality relation, also copied and and renamed.

```
axiomatization
equal :: "i_play => i_play => u_play" (infix "EQ" 50)
where
refl [intro]: "x EQ x" and
subst [elim]: "x EQ y ⟹ B x ⟹ B y"
```

This gives an `Type unification failed: Clash of types "u_play" and "bool"` error. When i replace u_play with bool all is fine and i can even use `EQ` in something trivial like `lemma t : "x EQ x"`, but the substitutionrule doesn't seem to work, which leads me to the question what are the two B's there. I've seen the same construct in HOL.thy with P's instead and a bit further down the isar rm they are omitted. Just stating `impD [dest]: (A --> B) ==> A ==> B`

What needs to be done to get the substitution to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theory `playground` imports `Main` that defines a lot. If you want to start from the bare grounds, you shall use `Pure` instead. Another issue is with `("_play" 5)` that should read `("_" 5)` (it defines a syntax). After these two changes you can proceed.

Comment: Thanks, those two did the trick. Can you expand on why "_" needs to be this way? And is there some way to get sledgehammer back into this?^^

Comment: @TKler, the underscore stands for an argument placeholder, and then the manual says: "Note that the object-logic judgment is implicit in the syntax: writing `A` produces `Trueprop A` internally". As another example with underscores you could use `"_ EQ _"` instead of `infix "EQ"`. As to the sledgehammer, it seems to expect some HOL theorems.